# SQL Date range selection

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

In Microsoft Access, I created a form with comboboxes where the user can select a certain date from a list of possible dates as start date. I then want the user to select the end date of the same list of possible dates (also a combobox).
Example:

Possible start dates (this is selected in combo box 20)

```
8/1/2015
9/1/2015
10/1/2015
11/1/2015
12/1/2015
```

Let's say the user picks 10/1/2015 as start date.

I then want the following list of dates to pop up from which the user can select end date:

```
11/1/2015
12/1/2015
```

I do not want the user to be able to pick an end date before that start date. The SQL code for the list of START DATES is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Item Master Spend].DateStamp
FROM [Item Master Spend]
WHERE ((([Item Master Spend].SupplierName)=[Forms]![Item Master Spend Supplier Overview]![Combo10]))
ORDER BY [Item Master Spend].DateStamp;
```

(combobox 10 is a list of suppliernames from which the user can choose. A list of possible start dates then pops up for that supplier)

SQL for list END DATES:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Item Master Spend].DateStamp
FROM [Item Master Spend]
WHERE ((([Item Master Spend].SupplierName)=[Forms]![Item Master Spend Supplier Overview]![Combo10]) 
AND [Item Master Spend].DateStamp > [Forms]![Item Master Spend Supplier Overview]![Combo20]);
```

The SQL for the end dates does not work. As soon as an user selects the start date, a pop up appears where I would have to manually type the end date.

Comment: What does the popup message ask for exactly? What is Combo20?

Comment: Do you have any event codes for Combo10? You say the popup occurs "As soon as an user selects the start date, a pop up appears where I would have to manually type the end date"